# how to read ssl certificate installed in windows mmc console in java

Tags: java, windows, ssl

I have followed this procedure to install ssl certifacate in my pc.

1. From Windows "start menu", clic on "execute" and enter "mmc"
   command.
2. Clic on "file","add/remove Snap in".
3. Choose  "Certificats" componant with "My user account" and OK.
4. In the "certificates - Current user" folder created, then do a right
   clic on "Trusted Publishers", "all Tasks", "Import" and browse for
   "keystore.cs" certificate.

How Can I read the keystore installed from the process above in java to enable ssl communication in my application. I need to use java HttpsConnection class to connect to the remote server.

Comment: [This is broadly the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34166304/243245), but none of the answers sound promising except maybe the JNI one, and I suspect that's out of date (but should still work). I'd be surprised if there wasn't already something on Maven to do this, but at first glance I can't find it.