# Unable to push docker image to heroku registry

Tags: java, docker, heroku, jib

I'm unable to push a docker image to the heroku registry.

I'm successfully logged in according to docker:

```
❯ docker login registry.heroku.com
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded
```

After that I run `mvn jib:build` and I get some confusing error saying I'm trying to push to an unsecure repo while the url in de output looks secure ( starts with https ).
What am I doing wrong ?

I'm using the following jib config:

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <to>
                    <image>registry.heroku.com/my-app</image>
                </to>
            </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Maven output of jib:build wiht -X:

```
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Build image failed, perhaps you should use a registry that supports HTTPS or set the configuration parameter 'allowInsecureRegistries'
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.maven.BuildImageMojo.execute (BuildImageMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.jib.api.InsecureRegistryException: Failed to verify the server at https://registry.heroku.com/v2/myapp/blobs/sha256:0fe85c64a011626a777c0662f83b2d819954d4148d96ca5fc626bf99f7c3644d because only secure connections are allowed.
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryEndpointCaller.call (RegistryEndpointCaller.java:180)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryEndpointCaller.call (RegistryEndpointCaller.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryClient.callRegistryEndpoint (RegistryClient.java:592)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryClient.checkBlob (RegistryClient.java:444)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.lambda$makeListForSelectiveDownload$1 (ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.call (ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.java:142)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.call (ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.java:43)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run (InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates (SSLSessionImpl.java:526)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:504)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute (MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.google.api.client.http.apache.v2.ApacheHttpRequest.execute (ApacheHttpRequest.java:73)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.http.FailoverHttpClient.call (FailoverHttpClient.java:323)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.http.FailoverHttpClient.call (FailoverHttpClient.java:250)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryEndpointCaller.call (RegistryEndpointCaller.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryEndpointCaller.call (RegistryEndpointCaller.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryClient.callRegistryEndpoint (RegistryClient.java:592)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryClient.checkBlob (RegistryClient.java:444)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.lambda$makeListForSelectiveDownload$1 (ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.call (ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.java:142)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.call (ObtainBaseImageLayerStep.java:43)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run (InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run (TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Do these links help you further? [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812972/failure-on-push-to-docker-registry-using-mvn-compile-jibbuild), [GitHub Issue 1](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/1216), [GitHub Issue 2](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/2074)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy to Heroku with Jib plugin you need to use the following properties:

```
    -Djib.to.auth.username=_
    -Djib.to.auth.password=$YOUR_HEROKU_API_TOKEN
    -Djib.to.image=registry.heroku.com/$YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME/web
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

The error indicates that your registry `registry.heroku.com` is insecure, or at least your system believes that it's insecure (unless there is a bug somewhere in the whole TLS verification flow, `registry.heroku.com` is mis-configured on the server side, or `registry.heroku.com` is hacked, which is uncommon). Using `https://` doesn't mean the connection is secure; it's secure only when you can verify the server. It's the same situation where the browser warns you when you visit an insecure site:

[image: insecure site]

This could also be due to a local proxy or firewall (because when I access `https://registry.heroku.com` on the browser, my browser can verify the server).

Some options:

1. Accept the risk and proceed by setting Jib's [`<allowInsecureRegistries>true`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#extended-usage). (Make sure no one is eavesdropping your connection and no system is compromised.)
2. *Assuming that the reason for being unable to verify the server is not because of a local proxy issue but because the server is using a self-signed certificate (i.e., the server certificate is not publicly endorsed)*: Secure your server (or make your system believe it's secure). The most practical solution would be to make your JVM believe that `registry.heroku.com` is secure by storing the self-signed certificate into your JVM's truststore. There are many how-to articles and posts. For example,

   - https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/self_sign_cert.md
   - https://davidjb.com/blog/2012/02/java-http-request-fails-with-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated/

   (However, I am not too sure if `registry.heroku.com` is using a self-signed certificate, as I said my browser can verify it. Something else may be going on with interfering your machine to verify the server. It's worth tracking down the root cause.)