# Java how to request users PKI cert automatically from browser/system?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, java-web-start, jnlp

Currently we have to prompt the user to find their .p12/jks cert file on disk using a file dialog box. They already have to add their cert to Chrome or FireFox so I was hoping to pull that information from there limiting the amount of steps they need to connect.

I noticed when launching the JNLP for the jar that it kind of already does this.

[image: PKI Cert Prompt]

So is it possible to have a similar window popup that I can then use to populate the system properties or is there a way to pass that information from the JNLP to the JAR. Ideally this is OS agnostic.

```
 System.setProperty(SSLEnvironmentBootstrap.SSL_KEYSTORE_KEY_NAME, keystore);
 System.setProperty(SSLEnvironmentBootstrap.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_KEY_NAME, keystorePassword);
```

Any and all suggestions or comments are appreciated it!

Comment: You would need to specify the OS used. Windows has an advantage of using a system-wide store (see [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166304/accessing-windows-certificate-store-certs-via-java) ). A system-agnostic interface would be pkcs#11 (such as a card reader)

Comment: I suspect thats going to be the issue most of our users are on linux, we develop on mac and a few users use windows. Linux would be the biggest user base though